# Overflow the PrimeNG DialogModule with the CalendarModule

Tags: css, angular, primeng

I want to build an Edit popup dialog with an input form in Angular2 using the PrimeNG widgets. I run into trouble with dynamic content of that dialog box (see screenshot).

[image: <p-calendar> in <p-dialog>]

I've naïvely been trying to wrap the CalendarModule in a div that is positioned above the other elements. (see Angular Template HTML below)

```
<p-dialog [(visible)]="display" [modal]="true" [resizable]="false">
...
<table class="ui-datatable-responsive">

<tbody>
  <tr>
    ...
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="ui-cell-data">Start By:</td>
    <td class="ui-cell-data">
      <div [style]="generateSafeStyle('position:relative; z-index:1000')">
        <p-calendar dateFormat="dd.mm.yy" [(ngModel)]="value"></p-calendar>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
 ...
</table>
</p-dialog>
```

However it seems the DialogModule frames all its content. Is there a hack to overflow that frame?

How would you handle that?

Thank you.

P.S: The generateSafeStyle Function just uses an injected DomSanitizer and works fine.

```
generateSafeStyle(style:string):SafeStyle{
 return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(style);
}
```

Comment: Please refer to my [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54802344/1506118) on another question. The same technique can be used here:

Answer (score 25):

just use appendTo="body", it will show calendar above all, even if it is in table, popup or scroll panel

`<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="invariable.value" dateFormat="mm/dd/yy" required appendTo="body" readonly></p-calendar>`

Comment: This didn't work for me.  Rather than the calendar appearing cropped in my popup <div>, now it appeared 100% width, at the very bottom of my browser window.    I actually want the calendar to appear *at the same place* on my browser window, but not cropped.

Comment: This works, it's the recommended (by PrimeNg )Solution for this case ;) thx^

Answer (score 10):

So I would guess things have changed since this was originally asked, but I found that if I added

```
[contentStyle]="{'overflow': 'visible'}"
```

to the p-dialog it allowed the calendar popup to overflow the dialog border.

Comment: That's the solution! Your beer is on me ;)

Comment: This worked for me in primeng 16 and Angular 16

Answer (score 4):

The only thing that worked so far were the following style options:

```
<p-calendar dateFormat="dd.mm.yy" [(ngModel)]="dueDate" [style]="{'position': 'fixed', 'overflow': 'visible', 'z-index': '999'}">
```

This however smashed up the table. So I got rid of the table and used flexboxes to align the elements. Looks better anyway like this.

Comment: I just set my position to relative and that fixed it.

Comment: This did not work for me because of the floating label. Had to use appendTo solution from @mAhESh

Answer (score 4):

It's related to overflow:auto on .ui-dialog-content

In dialog there is a div with class .ui-dialog-content make overflow:visible in that div and it will fix this problem.

Comment: Yup, this was the solution for my issue, using my own popup.  I didn't realise that adding "overflow:visible" actually has a different behavior to not having an "overflow" setting in there at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you check [official PrimeNG Calendar documentation](http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar), you will find list of attributes for calendar component, among them there's `style` attribute which you can use to add needed CSS:

```
<p-calendar dateFormat="dd.mm.yy" [(ngModel)]="value"
[style]="{ 'position': 'relative', 'z-index': '1000' }"></p-calendar>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I do, just with the DomSanitizer.  If I do it as you state, it additionally produces this beautiful warning: "WARNING: sanitizing unsafe style value [object Object] (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)."

Comment: @YvonneReinhardt I don't think you need to use `DomSanitizer`. I just tested the code I provided and it's working without any issues/warnings.

Comment: Okay, I might not need the div, and then I don't get any warning without the DOMSanitizer as well. However, this is not the issue, because the CalendarModule is still framed within the DialogModule and its ugly scrollbars... *grrr* Thanks for trying :-)

Comment: @YvonneReinhardt That's CSS problem then, but this is how style is applied to `p-calendar`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a better solution for this. Just add a method on click listeners and select element ui date picker
(click)="modifyStyle()"

In ts file import elementRef and Renderer2
constructor(private ele: ElementRef, private ren: Renderer2)
{}

```
modifyStyle()
{
 let ui = this.ele.nativeElement.querySelector(".ui-datepicker");

if(ui)
this.ren.setStyle(ui, "top", "unset")
 }
```

That's it.